# Make div fill parent height (jsfiddle)

Tags: html, css

Concrete use case:

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/271/

There this a twitter bootstrap tabs, and content of the tab contains: menu layer (fixed but unknown height), and second part that I want to fill the rest space of the tab pane.

So, I need yellow pane to fill rest of lightgray space (excepting 10px padding) and red content fill yellow space (except padding of course).

What is the best way to do that, is it possible without absolute positioning of the tab-pane?

The code (it is better to look fiddle):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tabs-above">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div class="input-prepend btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle">Select</button>
                            <select class="span1" ></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                        Scrollable content<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</diV>​
```

Css:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;          
    background: lightgray;        
    padding: 10px;
}

.tab-pane {
    background: yellow;            
    padding: 10px;
}

.content {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709337/css-stretch-div-to-100-of-its-parents-height-with-margin-padding) has a suggestion that would work for you.

Update your `tab-pane` and `content` classes:

```
.tab-pane {
    background: yellow;            
    padding: 10px;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position:absolute;
}

.content {
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px; right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    top: 50px;   
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/274/).

Comment: Well, thanks. But actually I understand how to do this with absolute positioning. You use top:55px; what if I don't know the height of navigation tabs? Is it possible to maintain normal flow (without using absolute)? that was in the question.

Comment: OK, the original question text asked: "is it possible without absolute layouts". You could replace the specific pixel value with a percentage to scale relative to the available space. Not sure if this will always work for you though.

Comment: So you sure, there is no way to do this without position: absolute? something like display: table, etc.

Comment: Not sure. You could use an actual table to for the layout:)

Comment: No, tables are not for me. -) I tried to implement solution given in that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212155/second-child-div-height-fill-parent-height but I couldn't. Actually absolute positioning ain't so bad for me, but wonder is it possible without hacks with standard flow of the page. (Thank, for the answer again, I will mark it as correct as soon I won't get any other appropriate)